# html_entity_decode not working for the first time

Tags: php, html

I have a string of html that I want to decode and strip off html tag before sending them out through email.

Here's the string :

```
<p>This is a test <em>please </em><strong>ignore </strong>it &gt;&lt;&nbsp;, thank you.</p>
```

After decode and strip off the html tags using html_entity_decode and strip_tags I still get some html entities left.

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str));
//got result as This is a test please ignore it &gt;&lt;&nbsp;, thank you.
```

Only doing another html_entity_decode would give me the correct result:

```
html_entity_decode(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str)));
```

- The string was taken directly from the post variable of CKEditor.

I don't understand why the first html_entity_decode doesn't do the trick and need another html_entity_decode. Could some please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the actual result you are looking for? and what are you getting? did you type `&gt;` into the editor?

Comment: Does the input have the entities double escaped?

Comment: I type < and > in the editor.

Comment: I tried to use mysql_real_escape before html_entity_decode but still doesn't help.